# Why does this function to convert all items in a list to strings not work?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a two dimensional array and I try to convert all items within each array to strings.

First I tried to use a function `to_str` and this approach didn't work. I do not understand why it doesn't work (it returns the input unchanged):

```
lst  = [['test1', 555], ['test2', 3333]]

def to_str(item):
    for i in item:
        if not isinstance(i, str):
            i = str(i)
    return item

output = list(map(lambda item:to_str(item), lst))

output: [['test1', 555], ['test2', 3333]]
```

Then I used a list comprehension instead, and it worked:

```
output = list(map(lambda item: [str(i) for i in item], lst))

output: [['test1', '555'], ['test2', '3333']]
```

Why does the first approach using `to_str` not work?

Comment: Step through it in a debugger. If you don't know how, learn it (e.g. video tutorial), but this would have made it trivial for you to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to modify the iteration variable named `i`. This has no effect at all, you're just rewriting the value of a local variable that points to a list element, but not changing the list itself. For this to work you have to modify the list elements at each index position, something like this:

```
def to_str(item):
    # iterate over the indexes in the item
    for i in range(len(item)):
        # we can remove this check, and simply convert everything to str
        if not isinstance(item[i], str):
            item[i] = str(item[i])
    return item
```

Or we can create a new list with the results, instead of overwriting the original (but this will be equivalent to using a list comprehension, better use a list comprehension):

```
def to_str(item):
    result = []
    for element in item:
        # we can remove this check, and simply convert everything to str
        if not isinstance(element, str):
            result.append(str(element))
        else:
            result.append(element)
    return result
```

Also, regarding your second approach: it'd be better if you avoid using `list`, `map` and `lambda`, if what you want is to create a new list as a result use a list comprehension directly. This is a more idiomatic way to solve the problem, also removing the unnecessary string check:

```
[[str(i) for i in item] for item in lst]
=> [['test1', '555'], ['test2', '3333']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Converted value i is not used anywhere in approach #1 and function just returns input

```
def to_str(item):
    result = []
    for i in item:
        if not isinstance(i, str):
            i = str(i)
        result.append(i)
    return result
```